# Is hash always preferable if I'm always getting multiple fields in redis?

Tags: redis

Let's say I am checking information about some of my users every second. I need to take an action on some of those users that may take more than a second. Something like this:

```
#pseudocode
users = DB.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE state=5");
users.forEach(user => { 
  if (user.needToDoThing()) {
    user.doThatThing();
  }
});
```

I want to make sure I won't accidentally run `doThatThing` on a user who has it already running. I am thinking of solving it by setting cache keys based on the user ID as things are processed

```
#pseudocode
runningUsers = redis.getMeThoseUsers();
users = DB.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE state=5 AND id  NOT IN (runningUsers)");
redis.setThoseUsers(users);
users.forEach(user => { 
  if (user.needToDoThing()) {
    user.doThatThing();
  }
  redis.unsetThatUser(user);
});
```

I am unsure if I should...

- Use one hash with a field per user
- Use multiple keys with mset and hget

Is there a performance or business reason I'd want one over the other? I am assuming I should use a hash so I can use `hgetall`  to know who is running on that hash vs doing a `scan` on something like  `runningusers:*`. Does that seem right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, option 1 (**Use one hash with a field per user**) is probably the best method in most cases because you want to access all fields for the users at once. It can be achieved by using `HGETALL`.

But when go you for 2nd option (**use multiple keys with mset and mget**) you want to query every single time in redis to get the user details.By using `MGET` you can access all key values but you want to know the key name for each users. It will be suitable when you are accessing few fields in an object.**Disadvantages:** possibly slower when you need to access all/most of the fields for the users.

**NOTE:** By using 1st option you can't set TTL for single users because in redis there is no support for TTL for child keys in hash structure,the only way you should set for entire hash.But by using 2nd option, you can set TTL for every single users.

Comment: Confused because you said option 2  is b est,  but i can use  hgetall? hgetall is for hash